# Xamarin.Forms. Swipe to previous page like Telegram

Tags: android, xamarin.ios, swipe

How create swipe to back?

In iOS:

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(HIPSTO.Controls.CustomContentPage), typeof(HIPSTO.iOS.Platform.Renderers.IOSPageRenderer))]     
namespace HIPSTO.iOS.Platform.Renderers 
{
    public class IOSPageRenderer : PageRenderer        
    {         
      public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)            
      {              
        base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

        ViewController.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Enabled = true;
        ViewController.NavigationController.InteractivePopGestureRecognizer.Delegate = new UIKit.UIGestureRecognizerDelegate();
       }
    }
}
```

But it only works from the edge. It is necessary from any place.
No ideas with android

As below shown:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

First, You could achieved by NavigationPageRenderer in android.

This is  GIF of this demo

[image]

TransitionNavigationPageRender.cs

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(SwipePageDemo.Controls.TransitionNavigationPage), typeof(TransitionNavigationPageRenderer))]
namespace SwipePageDemo.Droid.Renderers
{
public class TransitionNavigationPageRenderer : NavigationPageRenderer
{


    public TransitionNavigationPageRenderer(Context context) : base(context)
    {
    }



    protected override void SetupPageTransition(Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentTransaction transaction, bool isPush)
    {

                if (isPush)
                {

                }
                else
                {
                    transaction.SetCustomAnimations(Resource.Animation.enter_left, Resource.Animation.exit_right,
                                                    Resource.Animation.enter_right, Resource.Animation.exit_left);
                }

    }
}
}
```

enter_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:propertyName="enter_from_left"
  android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
  android:fromXDelta="-100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
  android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

enter_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
  <translate
     android:fromXDelta="100%" android:toXDelta="0%"
     android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
     android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

exit_left.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
 <translate
  android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="-100%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
  android:duration="300"/>
</set>
```

exit_right.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false">
<translate
  android:fromXDelta="0%" android:toXDelta="100%"
  android:fromYDelta="0%" android:toYDelta="0%"
  android:duration="300" />
</set>
```

If you want to know more details about Page Transition , you could refer to this link.
https://github.com/jsuarezruiz/xamarin-forms-page-transitions

**But it only works from the edge. It is necessary from any place**

You could achieved it by `threshold` property of `SwipeGestureRecognizer` class

[The SwipeGestureRecognizer class also includes a Threshold property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/gestures/swipe), that can be optionally set to a uint value that represents the minimum swipe distance that must be achieved for a swipe to be recognized, in device-independent units. The default value of this property is 100, meaning that any swipes that are less than 100 device-independent units will be ignored. If you want to increase the area that can be swiped, you could reduce this data of Threshold like following code.

```
        var leftSwipeGesture = new SwipeGestureRecognizer { Direction = SwipeDirection.Right };
        leftSwipeGesture.Threshold = 50;
        leftSwipeGesture.Swiped += (sender, e) => Navigation.PopAsync();
       stackLayout.GestureRecognizers.Add(leftSwipeGesture);
```

I changed value of leftSwipeGesture.Threshold to 50, this is GIF of swipe.
[image]

Comment: Thank you. But swipe fulfills after raising a finger. And I need to move page by finger.

Comment: Based on my research, i cannot be achieved in android of forms , but it can be achieved in original android. Beacuse original android achieved by extend actionbar activity or ViewDragHelper, forms achieved by frame.